# Updating a list in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to update the values in a list on netlogo.
The code here is my collision function: one breed collides into another, turns the circle black and then I want it to store the 'who' number of the 'found' circle in a list.

It currently just outputs the who number of each found one and prints a 'list' of one number each time.

Here's the code.

```
to collide2
  if any? circles2-on neighbors [
     set mylist [] ; not sure why I need this but 
                   ;doesn't work otherwise
     set whovalue [who] of circles2-on neighbors 
     set mylist lput whovalue  mylist
     ask circles2-on neighbors [set color black]
     output-print mylist
     ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple `circles-on neighbors`, then the code `[who] of circles-2 on neighbors` will return a list of their values of the `who` ID. You need the `sentence` command to concatenate two lists, using `lput` will add the list as one item in a list. For example: `print lput [1 2] [3 4]` will print out the list [3 4 [1 2]]. In your case, you are adding this to an empty list so the created list only has one element, and that element is itself a list.

But if your goal is to get a list of the `who` values, you don't need to do anything that complicated. The code `let whovalues [who] of circles2-on neighbors` will create a list automatically, because `of` creates a list.

So your code could be replaced with:

```
to collide2
  if any? circles2-on neighbors
  [ set whovalues [who] of circles2-on neighbors 
    ask circles2-on neighbors [set color black]
    output-print whovalues
  ]
end
```

However, see how you're having to keep track of the `who` values but then separately re-find all the neighbouring turtles? This is because you are storing the `who` values instead of storing the agents themselves. It is almost always better to refer to agents directly rather than identify them via their `who` value, so you can avoid awkward code like: `ask turtle with [who = <some value>] [do-something]`.

So, switching to turtles instead of `who`, and also switching to agentsets rather than lists (not essential but lists are only relevant if you need to track the order or have multiple instances etc):

```
to collide2
  if any? circles2-on neighbors
  [ set colliders circles2-on neighbors 
    ask colliders [set color black]
    output-print colliders
  ]
end
```

So now it is clear that the same turtles are being found and turned black. Even better, you can do this so that the agentset is only created once (more efficient as well as easier to read):

```
to collide2
  let colliders circles2-on neighbors
  if any? colliders
  [ ask colliders [set color black]
    output-print colliders
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I do want to store which turtles have been found so that I only receive the data once for each 'found' circle.

Comment: I thought you might, it's particularly common with people who have programmed in other languages before coming to NetLogo because lists of identifiers is the way other languages often work. If you find yourself using `who`, then there is almost always a way to do it that is more NetLogo-y, faster and cleaner with agentsets (or lists of agents if order is important etc).